# MySQL show this year value and last year from same table

Tags: mysql

I'm pretty new to mysql, but I have a table that looks like this:

```
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| id | year | month | total | cost |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
|  1 | 2011 | Dec   |  2000 | 2048 |
|  2 | 2012 | Jan   |  2675 | 2738 |
|  3 | 2012 | Feb   |  2685 | 2749 |
|  4 | 2012 | Mar   |  1787 | 1830 |
|  5 | 2012 | Apr   |  1547 | 1584 |
|  6 | 2012 | May   |   847 |  867 |
|  7 | 2012 | Jun   |   621 |  636 |
|  8 | 2012 | Jul   |   610 |  624 |
|  9 | 2012 | Aug   |   659 |  675 |
| 10 | 2012 | Sep   |   828 |  848 |
| 11 | 2012 | Oct   |  1420 | 1454 |
| 12 | 2012 | Nov   |  1608 | 1646 |
| 13 | 2012 | Dec   |  2721 | 2786 |
| 14 | 2013 | Jan   |  2636 | 2699 |
| 15 | 2013 | Feb   |  2266 | 2320 |
| 16 | 2013 | Mar   |  2351 | 2407 |
| 17 | 2013 | Apr   |  1497 | 1532 |
| 18 | 2013 | May   |   819 |  838 |
| 19 | 2013 | Jun   |   668 |  684 |
| 20 | 2013 | Jul   |   580 |  594 |
| 21 | 2013 | Aug   |   623 |  638 |
| 22 | 2013 | Sep   |   790 |  808 |
| 23 | 2013 | Oct   |  1146 | 1173 |
| 24 | 2013 | Nov   |  1581 | 1618 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
```

I need a query that gives me the results (cost) as this:

```
+-------+-------+------+
| month |  2012 | 2013 |
+-------+-------+------+
| Sep   |   848 |  808 |
| Oct   |  1454 | 1173 |
| Nov   |  1646 | 1618 |
+-------+-------+------+
```

I'm following the electrical consumption and need to see month this year and previous year. Any ideas?

Comment: That's a pivot query, and mysql doesn't support them directly. for just two columns, the work arounds are tedious/ugly but doable. If you need an arbitrary number of year columns, then don't do it in sql. Do the transformation in your client-side code.

Answer (score 1):

```
select month, 
       sum(case when year = 2012 then cost else 0 end) as 2012,
       sum(case when year = 2013 then cost else 0 end) as 2013
from your_table
where month in ('Sep','Oct','Nov') and year in (2012,2013)
group by month
```

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't ever written a query to produce the results you are looking for, after doing some research about your given issue, I came across this possible solution found here:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,75357,75357#msg-75357

Please reference the replies in which someone makes use of the MAX() function within the creation of a view that may produce the results you need.

And since this will create a view for you, you won't need to rerun the query everytime, instead you could just view the contents of the view and even run queries against the view!

Here is the query based on the answer provide in the link above that I formulated to fit your needs, please test this and replace `YOUR_TABLE_NAME` with your table name.

```
CREATE VIEW monthly_info_view AS
    SELECT  month,
            MAX( IF(year=2011,value,'') ) AS '2011',
            MAX( IF(year=2012,value,'') ) AS '2012',
            MAX( IF(year=2013,value,'') ) AS '2013'
    FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME
    GROUP BY month
```

What makes this not so good is that you'll have to modify this view every year to add the new year's respective column.

Comment: You know linked answer are considered bad answers,even from mysql forums.Post the relevant content in your answer.

Comment: While I don't necessarily agree with that philosophy as I think teaching people how to formulate/resolve their issue is more important than simply giving them the answer, I've updated my post to provide a query that may work.  Thanks.